# How to use shared C# project in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I have a problem that's been hunting me for weeks.

I have the following setup :

- Server (C# project)
- Shared (Library)
- Client (Unity project)

Where both the Server and Client use the Shared library.

Right now, I manually build and copy the shared.dll to the Assets folder of the Unity project.

I find it really cumbersome. I'm looking for an automatic way and I did some research and learned that since Unity rebuilds the project file, you can't link a project to it because it will automatically get deleted on rebuild.

My question is : How do I link an external Project to Unity?

Comment: Add the reference in your solution file.

Comment: It gets removed on rebuild

Comment: You have three different projects, yes?  Add them all to the same solution.

Comment: Yes I have three different project. I'm not sure, is it possible to add a Unity project to an existing solution? I searched but couldn't find.

Comment: As long as it's following the `csproj` standard, yeah

Comment: Wow okay it works. Nice! Weird how I couldn't find anything how to do it. Maybe it was too simple for anyone to wonder about. Can you make a response? I don't want to answer my own post.

Comment: Note : It only works in Visual Studio. In JetBrains Rider, it says the .csproj file is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that I am aware of.

The first and simplest is to use Microsoft's MSBuildForUnity (which was created after the original post) https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildForUnity/blob/master/Samples/IntegratedDependencies.Unity/README.md which is build for this very purpose.

The alternative (which was possible at the time of  the original post) is to use the undocumented process of creating a subclass of `AssetPostprocessor` and create the function `private static string OnGeneratedSlnSolution(string path, string content)` to manually manipulate the `sln` file that Unity will generate to include your references to your shared library.

This way, each time that Unity recreated the `sln` file, it will now also include your reference. The down-side is that the content comes in as a `String` so you may want to parse it through more libraries to make sure that you have a valid result or make your solution very rigid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with a similar setup. Using Visual studio I just changed the build directory, to that of the assets folder, in the Project properties -> build

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio (2017):

- Right-click your `Solution` from the `Solution Explorer`
- `Add`
- `Existing Project...`

Then navigate to your Unity or Shared Library project's `.csproj` file and select `Open`.

Comment: Okay, it was working fine for a few seconds, but it's asking for the reference to be re-added. Using Jetbrains Rider

Comment: That's quite weird.  It might be a bug with Rider or that might need some other process?